# http timeout even after making a server call ( ajax call ) every 3 mins (180 sec) to have server respond and keep the http connection alive

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-web-app-service

i am working on a django application currently deployed on azure app service.i includes generation of report in docx. format. in some scenerios i takes upto 5-6 minutes. at first i encountered activity timeout after 70 sec which i solved by using applicationHost.xdt to configure activitytimeout and request timeout.
then another timeout happened after 230 sec almost. which according to my knowledge is due to load balancer. i understand it is not configurable in app service.. do i tried another technique which basically does is that it keeps pinging backend from client after every 180 sec. but the problem didn't go away. pasting detailed code below. 
Thanks in advance

```
   function pinger(stop)
{
  if (status == true)
  {
    return;
  }
  else
  {
    $.ajax({
    async   : false,  
    url:"{% url 'DummyUrl' %}",
    type: "GET",
    data: {},
    beforeSend:function()
    { 
      console.log('starting dummy')
    },
    success:function(response){
    console.log('success dummy')

    console.log(response.data) 
    },
    complete:function(){},
    error:function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError){}

  });
  return;
  }

}

    function generate_report()
{   
    var status = false; 
    $.ajax({
    async   : true,
    url:"{% url 'GenerateReport' %}",
    headers: { "X-CSRFToken": '{{csrf_token}}' },
    type: "POST",
    data: {},
    beforeSend:function()
    {    
      console.log('starting');
      console.log('readonly');
    },
    success:function(response){
      if (response.data.toString().includes('.docx'))
          {
            console.log(response);
            var url_mask = "{% url 'download report' filename=12345 %}".replace(/12345/, response.data.toString());
            console.log('document generated successfully here is the link');
            status = true;
            show_download_link(url_mask);

          }

      else{ console.log(response)}

      },
    complete:function(){
      console.log('completed')
    },
    error:function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError){
      Error_Link();
      console.log('error+')
    }

  });

         // pinger(stop)
  setTimeout(function(){ pinger(status); }, 180000);
  // setInterval(pinger(stop) , 120000);



}

   $("#generate_report_form").on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

   generate_report();

});
```

the code above calls two APIs simultaneously one for report generation and one for keeping connection alive. but timeout still happens. Please help....

Comment: Just timeout? Any error information? May you need to post some sreenshots of the network tab of developer tools of your browser.

Comment: it gives 500 error on console.it used to do the same when i encountered activity timeout

Comment: You may select some important errors you think to post here.

Comment: hmm. will post whatever i have